# BigQuery: Insert dynamic folder name into an EXPORT DATA statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to dynamically set a folder name on a data export.

 The below creates a folder called "@date" and does not input the actual date variable.

Is this possible to insert dynamic values into the uri?

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 

"EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(uri='gs://bucket/folder/@date/*.csv',  format='CSV',   overwrite=true,  header=true,  field_delimiter=',') AS SELECT field1, field2 FROM `dataset.table` ORDER BY field1 LIMIT 10"

USING CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS STRING) as date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another approach to insert a formatted timestamp that feels simpler.

See the **'|| timestamp ||'** section within the uri below

```
"EXPORT DATA OPTIONS ( uri='gs://bucket/folder-
'|| FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F-%T", TIMESTAMP_ADD(Current_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)) ||'
-*.csv',  format='CSV',   overwrite=true,  header=true,  field_delimiter=',') AS SELECT field1, field2 FROM `dataset.table` "
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer may not be suitable for your answer, but might help others who came across my situation where the file name with GCS path must be passed as an input parameter like below:

```
StoredProcedures_Offers(filePath STRING)
```

then this **filePath** needs to passed into `EXPORT DATA OPTIONS` uri section as follows:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS( uri=""||filePath||"", format='JSON', overwrite=true) AS
```

*Note: Excluding query part here in the answer just to highlight the EXPORT section*

Answer (score 0):

Try [concat](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT(
    "EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(uri='gs://bucket/folder/",
    CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS STRING),
    "/*.csv',  format='CSV',   overwrite=true,  header=true,  field_delimiter=',') AS SELECT field1, field2 FROM `dataset.table` ORDER BY field1 LIMIT 10"
)
```

Comment: your answer was great but I stumbled across another approach that I prefer and have added that as an answer.